# Tabela Expansível como fazer Duplo select?

Tags: php, mysql

Neste *script* um tenho uma tabela expansível Mostrando por `GROUP by nome` , que ao clicarmos na linha, expandirá, mostrando uma segunda tabela listando todas as linhas referente ao `GROUP by nome`.

Tabela Fechada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela Aberta: Como deveria mostrar

<kbd>[image: Tabela Aberta]</kbd>

O que eu não sei como fazer é que essa tabela filha mostre todos os registros referente a tabela mãe que mostram em `GROUP by nome`.

```
    <?php
    include"config.php";
    ?>
    <script  
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"  
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#report > tbody > tr").hide();
    $("#report > tbody > tr:even").addClass("odd").show();

    $("#report tr.odd").click(function () {
    $(this).next("tr").toggle();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
  });
  });
  </script>        
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="report" border="1" style="width: 50%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 20%;">Id</th>
            <th>Cliente</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM a_finan GROUP by cliente ";

  $result = $PDO->query( $sql );
  $linha = $result->fetchAll();
  foreach ($linha as $row) {

  $id_empresa = $row['id_empresa'];
  $id_finan = $row['id_finan'];
  $start = $row['start'];
  $tipo = $row['tipo'];
  $valor = $row['valor'];
  $os = $row['os'];
  $cliente  = $row['cliente'];
  ?> 

  <tr>
  <td> <a href="#"><?php  echo $id_finan?> Mostrar Faturas</a></td>
       <td><?php  echo $nome_fan?></td>
       <td>30,00</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                        <td>OS</td>
                        <td>Cliente</td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                        <td>Centro Custo</td>
                        <td>Status Transacação</td>
                        <td>valor</td>
                        <td>Acao</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $id_finan?></td>
                        <td><?echo $cliente?></td>
                        <td>12/10/2015</td>
                        <td>xxx</td>
                        <td>xxx</td>
                        <td>30,00</td>
                        <td>Del</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
       <?}?>
    </tbody>
    </table> 
    </body>
```

Comment: Não percebi nada... Qual é a dúvida mesmo?

Comment: Na tabela acima tem dois registros com id 1037 e 1043 elas estão agrupadas pelo nome. até aqui tudo certo.... o problema e como fazer quando eu clico no link "mostrar faturas" ao expandir a linha mostar os registros desagrupados aqui esta o script funcionando sem os selects https://jsfiddle.net/gxr47dqr/1/

Comment: Fabio esse fiddle é de como deveria ser ou de como está atualmente?

Comment: ele é só um exemplo de como deveria ser esse na pratica

Comment: Como assim desagrupados ? Não deu para entender ao certo qual é o problema.

Comment: Na tabela mãe na imagem acima ela fechada faz um select usando um Group by nome, agrupando todas as linha com o mesmo nome.    Oque eu quero e  que ao clicarmos no link ao expandir a linha mostre as linhas que foram agrupadas pelo Group by nome.

Comment: Você tem a lista agrupada que seriam os clientes, cada cliente tem seu ID correto? Se for correto, quando você clicar no link para "mostrar faturas" clie uma função onclick JS no link e faça um AJAX passando para a busca o ID do cliente, com esse ID você faz o select das faturas e monta o HTML por AJAX.

Comment: Como está estruturada as tuas tabelas? Quais são os campos e quais os valores que serão buscados? Sabendo de como elas trabalham, fica mais fácil ajudar.

Comment: @MayronCeccon infelizmente não sei nada de javascript e ajax.

Comment: Ola amigo pensa numa tabela simples e unica. onde os campos são ( id,cliente,data,tel,status,valor).  Na linha mãe mostrar (id,cliente,valor) agrupados pela coluna cliente. e  na linha expandida mostar todas ( id,cliente,data,tel,status,valor) referente ao cliente agrupado.

Comment: @MayronCeccon converti a tua resposta em comentário. Se quiseres podes dar uma resposta completa, com exemplos de código para o AP perceber o problema e a solução.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar a seguinte query:

`SELECT distinct cliente, data, group_concat(CONCAT_WS(',',id,coluna1,coluna2,valor) SEPARATOR ';') as resultados FROM tabela GROUP BY cliente ORDER BY cliente;`

Onde `CONCAT_WS(',',id,coluna1,coluna2,valor)` irá agrupar as colunas `id, coluna1, coluna2 e valor` e `group_concat([expr] SEPARATOR ';')` irá agrupar as linhas e separar por `;`

Você terá o seguinte resultado:

```
+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| cliente        | data | resultados                                   |
+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|    CVC Turismo |   30 | 1,xxx,xxx,30;4,xxx,xxx,30;6,xxx,xxx,30;      | 
| Sterna Viagens |   30 | 2,xxx,xxx,30;3,xxx,xxx,30;5,xxx,xxx,30;      |
+----------------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

O tratamento da coluna `resultados`, você pode fazer no próprio PHP. Ex.:

```
 $sql = "SELECT distinct cliente, data, group_concat(CONCAT_WS(',',id,coluna1,coluna2,valor) SEPARATOR ';') as resultados FROM tabela GROUP BY cliente ORDER BY cliente;";

 $result = $PDO->query( $sql );

 $linha = $result->fetchAll();
 foreach ($linha as $row) {
     $resultadoLinhas = explode(';',$row['resultados']);
     foreach ($resultadoLinhas as $resultadoLinha) {
         $resultadoColunas = explode(',', $resultadoLinha);
         $id      = $resultadoColunas[0];
         $coluna1 = $resultadoColunas[1];
         $coluna2 = $resultadoColunas[2];
         $valor   = $resultadoColunas[3];

         // No checkbox passe o id da linha no valor do input
         echo "<input type='checkbox' value='{$id}'>";
     }
 }
```

Neste link têm algumas informações interessantes sobre o agrupamento de resultado no MySQL, vale a pena conferir: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: Ola Carlos no meu aqui esta dando um erro  Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /  linha 14         http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f157db47d1c9b81a8716a92844317c1daf9d5903

Comment: Olá @FabioHenrique no link que passou você tenta executar a função `query` sem antes ter iniciado a classe PDO. Tente pôr na linha anterior o `$PDO = connect();`

Comment: Muito bom isso mesmo que precisava

Answer (score 0):

Olá, faça o seguinte:

Não Utilize GROUP BY, pegue todas as linhas, vamos trabalhas o agrupamento no PHP.

Você terá um array parecido com esse:

```
[0] => id,cliente,data,tel,status,valor
[1] => id,cliente,data,tel,status,valor
[2] => id,cliente,data,tel,status,valor
```

Agora utilize um foreach para percorrer todos eles e agrupar por id, cliente, valor.

Mais ou menos assim:

```
$result_novo = array();

foreach ($result as $key => $item) {
    $result_novo[$item['id']]['id']      = $item['id'];
    $result_novo[$item['id']]['cliente'] = $item['cliente'];
$result_novo[$item['id']]['detalhes'][$item['algumid']]['valor'] = $item['valor'];   

$result_novo[$item['id']]['detalhes'][$item['algumid']]['data'] = $item['data'];   


}
```

Na chave algumid utilize uma coluna valida para chave do array.

E agora para exibir no HTML, faça dois foreach, o primeiro normal e o segundo dentro do primeiro, que no exemplo acima fica na chave detalhes, assim você monta duas tabela, depois é utilizar um pouco de JQuery para abrir e fechar.

```
foreach $result_novo as $key => $item

echo $item['id'];
echo $item['cliente'];

if $item['detalhes'] == array {

foreach $item['detalhes'] as $key2 => $item2 {
   echo $item2['valor'];
   echo $item2['data'];
}

}

}
```

Obs: Utilize apenas a logica dos códigos.

Abraço !!